# Does stack persist through external calls?

Tags: solidity, security, assembly

Looking through the docs I found that a malicious caller can take the stack depth to ~1000 and then make a call which would fail due to stack depth. Based on that let's assume that stack indeed persists through calls.

So, is it possible that an entity can make a legit contract call their malicious contract and then use the `SWAP16` opcode to manipulate the `15th` stack value even though it was not meant to be accessible?

Like consider this

```
function sendEtherAndCall(address maliciousRecipient) external preventRentrant{
 uint someEther = balances[maliciousRecipient];
 balances[maliciousRecipient] = 0;
 bool success = maliciousRecipient.send(someEther);
 maliciousContract.call("Some function that uses SWAP 16");
 if(!success) balances[maliciousRecipient] = someValue; // Send failed
}
```

Is it possible to do this? Can the malicious contract use something like

```
PUSH false
SWAP16
```

Which makes the `bool success` as `false` even though it was successful? I just assumed that bottom 15th value would be the `bool success`. But is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The malicious recipient contract doesn't have access to the caller contract's stack.

There are two separate stacks:
a local stack where variables are pushed and removed (accessible only to the contract instance being executed); a global call stack where the the calls are stored (it is not accessible to contract).

Comment: So the global EVM stack let's say has the per contract stack pushed onto it just as some local variable? So the bigger stack manages the per contract stack and prevents inter stack OPs?

Comment: The "global stack" doesn't exists as such, it is just a concept where calls between contracts are tracked. It doesn't contain anything else, its purpose is to enforce de 1024 call deep.

Comment: Okay. So, the scope of stack is the contract call and scope of memory is function call is that correct? And the said global watching stack’s scope is whole message call?

Comment: The "global stack" scope is the whole transaction execution. The "local stack" and memory have the same stock: the contract call.

Comment: Isn't memory wiped off between function calls? Like iirc memory is not accessible in between function calls right, not even internal calls?

Comment: Yes, memory and local stack is wiped after a call has completed.